# Anchor Link behavior/Problem with .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I finished a Wordpress site but I'm having trouble with two anchor Links.
I have two columns that are supposed to expand when the anchor Link is clicked with only one open at a time.
The expanding and collapsing is done with CSS and the :active pseudo class but it only gets triggered when the anchor link is added to the URL.

I've boiled it down to the .htaccess file, since there are no JS files that are interrupting.
Right now I have added these lines to the config but it doesn't work as expected:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !referenzen\.php      [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/referenzen/([^/]+)/? [NC]
RewriteRule .*       /referenzen.php#%1           [R,NE,L]
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Why are you seemingly redirecting to a `.php` file? (This is a WordPress site after all.) "I've boiled it down to the .htaccess file" - So what is the problem with the `.htaccess` file that prompted you to try to "fix" it? Why is the "anchor link" (aka fragment identifier) not in the URL to begin with if it is required? However, redirecting in this way is going to deliver a bad user experience. The whole point of expanding/collapsing with CSS (or JS) is that there is no external redirect.

Comment: I'm not trying to redirect to a .php file, I want the .htaccess file to "allow" adding the anchor link to a specific URL e.g. the mentioned .php file. If I only use the last line of code it works fine on the specific page but it also messes up all of the other pages

Comment: But why are you linking to PHP files in the first place - in a WordPress system?

Comment: Also unclear, why it should _need_ URL rewriting in the first place, just to make anchors work? _"but it only gets triggered when the anchor link is added to the URL."_ - then why don't you do that in the place where you _set_ the link?

Comment: "I'm not trying to redirect to a .php file" - Although that's precisely what you appear to be doing in the rule you've posted and you've not stated otherwise. "I want the .htaccess file to "allow" adding the anchor link" - The `.htaccess` file does not do anything to _prevent_ the _fragid_ from being added to the URL (it's never sent to the server; it is entirely client-side) - so your "problem" is likely _somewhere else_. The _fragid_ ("anchor link") should be present on the URL in the client-side HTML - is it not?

Comment: "If I only use the last line of code it works fine on the specific page but it also messes up all of the other pages" - That last line of code does not make sense by itself and would cause a redirect-loop (depending where you've put it).